# Изменить элемент управления windows forms из асинхронного события

Tags: c#, winforms, telegram-bot

Есть телеграм-бот с событием OnMessage. На форме находится logList типа ListBox, куда я хочу записывать некоторый лог из телеграма. Так как OnMessage событие асинхронное, я не могу никак понять как изменить элемент управления или хотя бы передать данные куда-нибудь чтобы можно было изменить список.

```
public Main()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            botClient = new TelegramBotClient("token");
            var bot = botClient.GetMeAsync().Result;
            botClient.OnMessage += BotClient_OnMessage;
            botClient.StartReceiving();
            logList.Items.Add("Бот начал приём сообщений.");
        }

        private static async void BotClient_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            var text = e?.Message?.Text;
            string answer;
            if (text == null)
                return;
            // здесь добавить запись
            //logList.Items.Add("Получено сообщение от пользователя: " + text);
            if (text == "/screen")
            {
                answer = "Отправка скриншота...";
                await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId: e.Message.Chat, answer).ConfigureAwait(false);

                var bitmap = new Bitmap(1920, 1080, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                Rectangle captureRectangle = Screen.AllScreens[0].Bounds;
                Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(captureRectangle.Left, captureRectangle.Top, 0, 0, captureRectangle.Size);
                bitmap.Save(screenSavingPath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                var fileStream = new FileStream(screenSavingPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read);
                await botClient.SendPhotoAsync(chatId: e.Message.Chat, photo: new InputOnlineFile(fileStream)).ConfigureAwait(false);
                fileStream.Close();
                File.Delete(screenSavingPath);
            }
        }
```

Comment: `this.Invoke((Action)(() => logList.Items.Add("Получено сообщение от пользователя: " + text)));`

Comment: Перенесите свой код из конструктора формы в обработчик события `Form.Load`. Никогда не вставляйте свой код в конструктор формы до тех пор, пока не узнаете, почему я вам это сказал.

Comment: @aepot спасибо! Сделал всё, как вы и посоветовали, заработало!

Comment: @aepot как я понял Action - это абстрактный класс, не имеющий параметров. А чем можно его заменить, чтобы можно было передать название метода, не имеющего параметров?

Comment: внутри лямбда-выражения можете писать что угодно, это просто блок кода, добавьте фигурные скобки только `(() => { logList.Items.Add("Получено сообщение от пользователя: " + text); ... })` можете хоть любой метод оттуда вызвать, суть в том, что все что внутри, будет вызвано в UI потоке.